# Golang, mysql: Error 1040: Too many connections

Tags: mysql, go

I'm using the github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql driver for go.

I open a database:

```
db, err := sql.Open("mysql", str)
```

Then I have two functions that are called 200 times each with following mysql code:

```
rows, err := db.Query("select name from beehives")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}       
defer rows.Close()
```

The second:

```
    err = db.QueryRow("select id, secret, shortname from beehives where shortname = ?", beehive).Scan(&id, &secre
    switch {
    case err == sql.ErrNoRows:
        err = errors.New("Beehive '"+beehive+"' not found.")
    case err != nil:
        panic("loginBeehive: "+ err.Error())
    default:
        // ... do the work
```

The first one is panicing.

How can there be more than one connection when I open the database only once and how do I close them?

Comment: Having exactly this problem, thanks a lot for asking!

Answer (score 42, accepted):

[sql.Open doesn't really open a connection to your database.](http://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB)

A sql.DB maintains a pool of connections to your database. Each time you query your database your program will try to get a connection from this pool or create a new one otherwise. These connections are than put back into the pool once you close them.

This is what `rows.Close()` does.
Your `db.QueryRow("...")` does the same thing internally when you call `Scan(...)`.

The basic problem is that you're creating too many queries, of which each one needs a connection, but you are not closing your connections fast enough. This way your program has to create a new connection for each query.

You can limit the maximum number of connections your program uses by calling [SetMaxOpenConns](http://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB.SetMaxOpenConns) on your sql.DB.

See http://go-database-sql.org/surprises.html for more information.

Comment: We had the same trouble with our production system. Later we found this post and tried it. It worked, as each connection occupies main memory we went out of room. Then we configured the SQL server and set connection expiry 1 second. Thanks, man you paved the path @nussjustin

Answer (score 8):

The `*DB` object that you get back from `sql.Open` doesn't corresponds to a *single* connection. It is better thought as a handle for the database: it manages a connection pool for you.

You can control the number of open connections with [`(*DB).SetMaxOpenConns](http://godoc.org/database/sql#DB.SetMaxOpenConns) and [its pair](http://godoc.org/database/sql#DB.SetMaxIdleConns) for idling connections.

So basically what happens here is that `db.Query` and `db.QueryRow` tries to acquire a connection for themselves and the DB handle doesn't put any restrictions on the number of simultaneous connections so your code panics when it opens more than what mysql can handle.

Answer (score 4):

Try to make prepared statements `db.Prepare(query string) (*Stmt, error)` and than `stmt.Query` or `stmt.Exec` and than `stmt.Close` to reuse connections.

Answer (score 3):

hi can you try close connection after used

```
db, err := sql.Open("mysql", str)
defer db.Close() // close after end scope
```

Answer (score 1):

My program is connecting always to database. (Realtime Face Recognition for Attendance)

Therefore opening and closing database connection is worthless.

Therefore it's keep opens the database connection only initializing the program.

```
func GetAllFaces() interface{} {
    OpenDatabaseConnection() ... 
}
```

But access database later, increased the no of connection and crashed the program. But closing the `rows` object kept no of active connection at minimum. (for me 1)

```
 func SaveAttendance(faceId int, date time.Time) error {
    sqlQuery := fmt.Sprintf("SELECT ... "))

    rows, err := DB.Query(sqlQuery) ...
    err = rows.Close()
    return err
}
```