# SetMaxOpenConns() not solving `Error 1040: Too many connections`

Tags: mysql, go

I am using golang with Mysql. I am testing load on server using `apache benchmark tool`. I am getting too many connections error. I read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28135580/golang-mysql-error-1040-too-many-connections) . So, I added `SetMaxOpenConns(100)` in my code. Still I am getting this too many connections error.

I am doing the following query

`ab -n 1000 -k -c 20 -p post.txt -T application/x-www-form-urlencoded http://localhost:8084/abcd`

**Note:** post.txt file contains array of 35 ids(type integer). This is my main function:

```
db, err := models.NewDB("root:@/rules")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    db.SetMaxOpenConns(100)
    http.Handle("/abcd", getReq(db))

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8084", nil))
```

I am querying this function in go routine for all the ids.

```
func getRuleforProduct(db *sql.DB, id int) map[int]string {
    m := make(map[int]string)
    var res string
    err := db.QueryRow("select rules from table where product_id = ?", id).Scan(&res)
    checkError(err)
    m[id] = res
    return m
}
```

How to solve this issue, even if request per second is less. I want the code to work for atleast 20 concurrent request.

Comment: what does netstat -antp look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should check how many open connections does your MySQL server allow with `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_connections'`. Default is 151 but if it's less than 100 then your program obviously tries to open too many connections.

But even if it's more than 100 you could still easily get that error. MySQL's `max_connections` is a global variable that affects the whole server. If your program uses other databases on same server they will also count towards your `max_connections` limit. Or similarly if you have other programs using your database server you can also run out of connections. In that case you have to use smaller values for `SetMaxOpenConns()` or increase the `max_connections` variable.

Also consider setting `db.SetMaxIdleConns()` To a value lower than `db.SetMaxOpenConns()`. Otherwise you might have 100 (or whatever value you gave to `SetMaxOpenConns`) idle connections to your database server using up your connection pool.

Answer (score 2):

To update the open conection limit and seeing that limit, you just need to login into the mysql and perform the following commands.

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_connections';
+-----------------+-------+
| Variable_name   | Value |
+-----------------+-------+
| max_connections | 90  |
+-----------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

The below command will set the limit of open connections to 1000, that can be changed as per your need.

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL max_connections = 1000;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_connections';
+-----------------+-------+
| Variable_name   | Value |
+-----------------+-------+
| max_connections | 90  |
+-----------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

For reference you can go to mysql official link from here [mysql link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set-variable.html)